# Bootstrap Dropdown shifts to bottom left

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

```
<div class="list-nav"><span>Application</span>
<span style="color:#a6a6a6">></span>
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
<button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn">
{{SelectedCluster}} <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li *ngFor="let cluster of Clusters"  role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-
item" href="/#/list/{{cluster}}">{{cluster}}</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[Code snippet along with how it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1jGY.png[1])
I am writing a dropdown menu using `ngxbootstrap` and `angular`. The dropdown button is located next to the "`>`". I expected the menu to pop out right under the button. However it shifts and pops up under the Application span. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your code here, not a picture of it.

Comment: try to make a codepen simple example with your code so we can actually help you

Comment: https://codepen.io/allenduncare/pen/VMezeL here you go, I couldn't add my angular code that grabs the data, but this should suffice.

Comment: Your demo is not working. Please fork from this and complete: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ey4seb

Comment: https://angular-esge7d.stackblitz.io I posted the code here and it seems to not work well with ngx-bootstrap. I have included http://i.stack.imgur.com/kUk1h.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1jGY.png to hopefully help with understanding my problem.

Answer (score 1):

small chance that list-nav is breaking dropdown positioning,
try to append it to body 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#container-body

if it helps, try to reproduce your dropdown only with html and css,
if issue persists please report it to bootstrap css github repo